# Full Stack of FirstChanceException

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Currently, we have a first chance exception handler setup on the Application Dommain using the following:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += FirstChanceHandler;
```

The problem with that solution is it only gives us the stack trace of the exact line and method that threw the error, instead of the ones that bubble up. We need to get the context of a method up the chain that is causing this exception.

The exception, is handled, and swallowed by a third-party library though (albeit, incorrectly so) but we still need that context, as there's additional information at that context in the third party library.

Currently we can get this by hijacking their logger, but that seems to be a bad idea; if their logging implementation changes, we have no access to the underlying information/context. The exception is far less likely to change, than the logging.

Is there a way to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually can't do what I want to do with it; for reasons that mostly make sense. But I did figure out the answer anyways, so for the benefit of any googlers, just use the following code, inside the event handler:

```
var stack = new StackTrace(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I needed.